# How can I import a .pfx file that was created without a password?

Tags: bouncycastle, pfx, pkcs#12

I have created a PFX PDU using the java bouncycastle library. Inside the PFX PDU, there are two certificates and two encrypted private keys. All the contents are used as PKCS#7 data content (i.e. no encryption, stored as octet strings).I organised the elements according to the guidelines of PKCS#12 ([RFC 7292 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#section-5)). Then I wrote the DER encoded byte array to a file.

I opened the file in a hex editor and saw that the object structure is OK. I have also read the file contents and built a bouncycastle PFX object from it. But when I try to open the .pfx file from my file system, the Certificate Import Wizard asks for the password for the private key. I did not use any password to create the PFX object. I have tried to use empty string and the password used for encrypting the private keys, but they didn't work. It shows "The password you entered is incorrect.".

Is there something I missed here? How can I get the password required to import certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RFC 7292, section 4.1, page 41, details of AuthenticatedSafe is described. AutthenticatedSafe is sequence OF ContentInfo which could one of three types.

```
AuthenticatedSafe ::= SEQUENCE OF ContentInfo
-- Data if unencrypted
-- EncryptedData if password-encrypted
-- EnvelopedData if public key-encrypted
```

Make your authenticatedSafe data as EncryptedData where you needs to encrypt the BERencoded value of AuthenticatedSafe with the SecretKey generated from password you will give using SecretKeyFactory and PBEParameterSpec.

Hope that, this will help you. Cheers !!!